# when I update an item in my recuclerlistview it put the changes in the previous item of recyclerlistview

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerlistView that retreives data from firebase and in each item there is a button that lets me choose and change a date with datePickerDialogue  but when I change date it put the changes in the previous item of recyclerlistview .

For example when I click btnEnable at item of position 1 in my list to change date it put the changes in the item of position 0

```
protected void onBindViewHolder( ViewHolder holder, ("RecyclerView") int position,  ModelUser model) {

    holder.tvEmail.setText("Email: "+model.getEmail());
    holder.tvName.setText("Name: "+model.getName());
    holder.tvUid.setText("Uid: "+model.getUid());
    holder.tvDate.setText("Date expiration : "+model.getDateExpiration());
    dialog= new Dialog(holder.tvName.getContext());



    // enable profile
    holder.btnEnable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            final int year = calendar.get(calendar.YEAR);
            final int month = calendar.get(calendar.MONTH);
            final int day = calendar.get(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            Toast.makeText(holder.tvDate.getContext(), "position  "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog= new DatePickerDialog(
                    v.getContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                    setListener,year,month,day);
             datePickerDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
             datePickerDialog.show();




            setListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    month = month+1;
                    String date = day+"/"+month+"/"+year ;
                    // holder.tvDate.setText("date expiration : "+date);

                    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("dateExpiration",date);

                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                            .child(getRef(position).getKey()).updateChildren(map)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                    Toast.makeText(holder.tvDate.getContext(), "date expiration has been updated"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(holder.tvDate.getContext(), "date expiration update failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
                }
            };


        }
    });



}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: for example when I click btnEnable at item of position 1 in my list  to change date it put the changes in the item of position 0

Comment: Are you saying that your `position` variable is off by 1? If so, can you edit your question to show how that variable is initialized?

Comment: protected void onBindViewHolder( ViewHolder holder, ("RecyclerView") int `position`,  ModelUser model) {    // enable  button profile }

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for. Thanks.